# How to add a word to the Voice Typing recognition list?

Tags: google-maps, customization, voice-recognition, dictionary

I need to frequently say the word "olivette". I added it to my keyboard dictionary. Voice Typing ALWAYS interprets it as "all of that". It doesn't learn from my correcting it.

A Google search reveals ways you USED to be able to add words to your phone's recognition list. Other services let you (e.g. dragon).

How do you do it on Android 8.0  and later? (I'm using a motorola z-play)

Answer (score 0):

With Gboard, there's currently no option to add a word to the Voice Typing recognition list. That's indeed one upside of using Dragon.